# TouchSpin Plugin not working on dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am creating a div with an input text dynamically. and I am applying `touchSpin()` like this.

```
$(".commission").TouchSpin({
        min: 0,
        max: 2,
        step: 0.0001,
        decimals: 4,
        boostat: 5,
        maxboostedstep: 10,
        buttondown_class: 'btn btn-white',
        buttonup_class: 'btn btn-white'
    });
```

This same code was working when Ithe content was static but now its loading using ajax call , and the plugin doesnot work

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pad">
    <input class="commission" type="text" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 pad">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right view_btn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_details" type="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Can any one suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you can write TouchSpin code inside ajax success function. like this:

                          $.ajax({
                            url: "/productos/fillItemView",
                            type:"GET",
                            data: {datos: JSON.stringify(data)},
                            dataType: "html",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                            success: function(result){

                            $("#initTr").after(result); //insert dynamic input with inputClass class in view


                            $(".inputClass").TouchSpin({
                                min: 0,
                                max: 100,
                                step: 1,
                                decimals: 0,
                            }).on('change', function(){
                                 //maybe optional
                            });
                            },
                            error : function(xhr, status) {
                                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                                    console.log(status);
                            },
                        })
                        .done(function(result){
                        });
```

Regards.